# Preimage of 0 for a differentiable function.

Tags: differential-topology

If a subset $N$ of a manifold $M$ can be written as $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ being $f:M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, can  I conclude that $N$ is a submanifold of $M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no, you can't: **every** closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is the zero set of a $\mathcal C^\infty$ map $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$.
Unbelievable? Maybe.
True? Definitely: this a theorem of Whitney, proved in [Madsen-Tornehave](http://books.google.se/books/about/From_Calculus_to_Cohomology.html?hl=sv&id=CwQ-L9MOGUwC) page 224.

Comment: IMO it is somewhat intuitive, once you think of the distance function $$d(x, A) = \inf_{y \in A} d(x,y)$$ You just need to plug it into something to smooth out the kink on the boundary; e.g. squaring the distance if you just want it to be once differentiable. Or am I totally wrong and this doesn't work?

Comment: Dear @Hurkyl, I don't know if your idea works but Whitney's proof is rather more complicated.

Comment: I bet the complication comes from considering an arbitrary manifold rather than just $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Consider for example $M=\mathbb R^2$ and $f(x,y)=xy$. Or, for a more dramatic example,
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}0 & x\le 0 \\
ye^{-1/x} & x > 0 \end{cases}$$